# Run logical test or calculation vs first of kind in separate index column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a large data frame with a column index which repeats a numerical value assigned to a particular row's activity.  I'd like to be able to run a calculate referencing this index column and counting the number of days from the first date containing that reference value as a separate column along with a separate column doing a logical test that the value contained in a separate column matches the first value for that index value in that column.  I've been using dplyr and have the following script:

```
 test <- InsiderList3 %>%
  group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>%
  mutate(rf.diff =  first(`Transaction Date`)-`Transaction Date`) %>%
  mutate(IssuerCheck =  first(`Issuer`) ==Issuer)
```

The column labeled "Insider CIK" is the index and all other columns' information is tied to this until the next index value pops up in which the process repeats.  There is a separate date column and information identifying the company.

dput for sample of first 20 rows:

```
   dput(head(InsiderList3[c('Insider CIK', 'Transaction Date', 'Issuer')], 75))
structure(list(`Insider CIK` = c("0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", 
"0001008134", "0001008134", "0001008134", "0001009891", "0001012859", 
"0001012859", "0001012859", "0001012859"), `Transaction Date` = structure(c(18358, 
18358, 18101, 18065, 18065, 18039, 17729, 17700, 17674, 17674, 
17345, 17345, 17326, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17014, 
17001, 16964, 16964, 16598, 16590, 16582, 16582, 16409, 16288, 
16288, 16245, 16245, 16217, 16161, 16072, 16052, 15967, 15880, 
15869, 15771, 15710, 15710, 15687, 15603, 15523, 15354, 15354, 
15030, 14979, 14840, 14049, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18358, 18358, 
18358, 18261), class = "Date"), Issuer = c("TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"SANDRIDGE ENERGY INC", "SANDRIDGE ENERGY INC", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "QUEST RESOURCE CORP", "QUEST RESOURCE CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", "CHESAPEAKE OILFIELD OPERATING LLC", 
"TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "QUEST RESOURCE CORP", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", "CVR ENERGY INC", "CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", 
"SANDRIDGE ENERGY INC", "TRANSATLANTIC PETROLEUM LTD.", "Seventy Seven Energy Inc.", 
"CHESAPEAKE ENERGY CORP", NA, "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", 
"NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP", "NATIONAL HEALTHCARE CORP")), row.names = c(NA, 
75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: `first(`Issuer`) =Issuer` needs `==`.

Comment: Maybe post `head(InsiderList3[c(`'Insider CIK'`, `'Transaction Date'`, `'Issuer'`)], 20)`? It's only 3 columns and 20 rows.

Comment: I've made that change but unfortunately it's still not working.  Each subsequent date calculate which should be relative to the first of its kind not the first overall isn't working (i have a few negative values).  The logical test also is tied to the first value in the table not vs the next value in the index.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but isn't it just a matter of sorting by `'Transaction date'`?

```
InsiderList3 %>%
  group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>%
  arrange(`Transaction Date`) %>%
  mutate(rf.diff =  first(`Transaction Date`) - `Transaction Date`,
         IssuerCheck =  first(`Issuer`) == Issuer)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not because you want to keep them in chronological sequence.  I will add a bigger portion to the dput.

Comment: @js80 Maybe `min` instead of `first`?

Comment: Using min unfortunately trims off the first CIK number's transaction log and produces NA's for the mutate variables. Because the date difference should be based off the first transaction date for a given CIK number it should never be negative.  0 should be the most recent date for a reported transaction related to that CIK number.